# Manipulating electro-magnetic fields through brain waves

Tags: internal-consistency

Let´s assume, there are electromagnetic fields holding several pairs of anti-matter and matter particles in reach of a human being.

Could a human brain somehow control this electromagnetic field, or better said, could this person make the matter particles annihilate each other by manipulating/ dissolving the electromagnetic field?

If not, what would it take a human brain to be able to do so?

Comment: Three points: first, the brain has [no mechanism](http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2189#comic) for long-distance manipulation of the electromagnetic field.  If it did, you can be sure that evolution would have found a way for us to use it.  Second, you may want to clarify what type of effect you're talking about: you can't "dissolve" the electromagnetic field any more than you can "dissolve gravity."  Lastly, all charged particles (protons and neutrons) interact with the electromagnetic field, the real question is how strongly and in what way?

Comment: electromagnetic fields is photon which is light, you brain generates power every now and then (provided you are at least not brain dead) in term of infrared radiation most commonly known as heat. When you visit a doctor for a brain scan, sometimes they will bombard your brain with antimatter (positrons) and watch it colliding with your own matter (electrons) using MRI scan. You mention about controlling... more visitation to clinic then perhaps they might refer you to a psychiatrist.

Comment: Your question is very much on the short, broad and vague side. May i suggest you take a tour of the help section, and after that elaborate a bit more on what your setup is, and most of all, on what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

This would take a specialized organ not only capable of generating large amounts of electrical current in various frequencies, but able to survive that current without burning up. This will not ever actually happen, and is perhaps best left to the willing suspension of disbelief.

If you must have this person have a debatable, organic reason they can do this, then the organ need not necessarily be in the brain, but will likely not be very pretty wherever it shows up. It will consume massive amounts of energy during use, making the character weak and hungry frequently. During use, it will probably be quite painful, due to involvement of the surrounding nervous system and heat generation. And in all likelihood, this person has a long list of other problems due to the state of his/her DNA; this isn't evolution, it's a mutation, and in real life this can get weird.

Seriously I'd just hand wave this.

Answer (score 0):

The human brain is notoriously weak when it comes to producing brain waves. From [this](http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-brain-waves-interfere-radio-waves) site:

> brain waves are so weak, they are hardly measurable at all. For comparison, says Pantazis, “the magnetic field of the earth is just strong enough to move the needle of a compass. Signals from the brain are a billionth of that strength.”

However, humans have managed to do exactly what you're asking for. The first operational use occurred on August 6, 1945, and the second three days later. This was achieved by the human brain directing the motions of the human body to conduct experiments, create designs, and build an atomic device. Today, we also have the [Large Hadron Collider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider), which we use to discover new things about physics by annihilating particles at near-*c* speeds.

The human brain may lack the power to directly influence electromagnetic fields, but it can formulate and direct the means to do so.

Comment: Atomic weapons do not contain, use, or release antimatter particles ([except for antineutrinos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235#Nuclear_weapons)).

Comment: @2012rcampion Atomic weapons don't utilize/include/operate on antimatter, but they do disrupt electromagnetic fields (splitting the atom), which is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: OP seems to be looking specifically for matter-antimatter annihilation.  Even chemical reactions and light 'disrupt electromagnetic fields' to the same extent that nuculear reactions do.

Comment: @2012rcampion I agree the OP is looking for particle annihilation, but the question was about disrupting the EM field separating particles. Lots of ways to do that; atomic destruction is just a little more fun than the others.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with a brain/machine interface.
There have been lots of stories in the news with people controlling robotic limbs and computer games using just their thoughts.
Assuming that the fields are being generated by a machine, then having a brain interface would work.

Otherwise, probably not unless you want to get into ESP or telekinesis or something semi magical.